# Which is the correct event to bind data to server controls?

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, datagridview

we have bunch of events in page life cycle of asp.net page . Which is the correct event to bind data to controls? page_load or prerender or any thing else ?

Answer (score 1):

Use `Page_Load` for that.

```
protected void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // remember to check the IsPostBack property, only databind on the first load 
    // if ViewState is enabled ( default ):
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        DataBindControls();
    }
}
```

If you would use `PreRender` it would be too late in the page's life-cycle since the Control events were already triggered. Consider that you databind a `GridView` and you want to handle a `TextBox.TextChanged`-event in a template-field, it would be too late for it.

[ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)

Comment: ok , if it is purely data binding means? that is i don't want to handle any event . In this case which event is best ?

Comment: Page_Load is normally used.

Comment: This is common, but often not useful. If you want to respond to any postback events, for example if you have a pager control and want to fetch only the items for that page, then Page_Load is too early.

Comment: @MarkVerrey: That's a different question. OP wants to know the best **page** event for databinding other controls. Of course, if you have to handle a control's event you have to use that event. So if you want to use a `DropDownList`'s `SelectedIndexChanged`-event to databind another control it's pointless to use `Page_Load`(or a different page-event). I assume OP wants to know when to databind controls the first time, not at postbacks.